# Is there an iterable write interface corresponding to IEnumerator<>?

Tags: c#

Or rather: is there a good reason not to have something akin to IEnumerator<>, just with a write-functionality? It looks like writing per an iterator is a somehow discouraged methodology for changing an basically iterable collection but I can't see why that is the case. What am I overlooking?

Comment: You are aware that instead we can have functions that performs "write" operations, but do return another IEnumerator and do not modify the existing one in-place, right ? `Union`, `Concat`, ...

Comment: Should indicate where you are seeing that it is discouraged.

Comment: No.  Put the Write statements into the IEnumerator<> or create an write Interface for  a IEnumerator Class.

Comment: @GSerg the answer you linked suggests in my eyes that it fails silently, so the failure was a side-effect of the implementation which has its focus (clearly and logically) on performance. But that is not what I was asking - my question is rather why e.g. `Queue<T>' can be read by an iterator but not modified out of the box by one (this is a real use case - e.g. add x to all queue elements because of event y)

Comment: @jdweng I don't quite understand this. How would you (without the ref-return functionality that Marc Gravell described) use the `.Current` access to write to the underlying data structure?

Comment: Marc code FOO is an interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recent versions of C# added `ref foreach`; this isn't mapped to an interface - you need to implement it manually, but: with `ref foreach`, you **can** change values via the iterator variable. Example:

```cs
using System;

class Foo
{
    public NotImplementedIterator GetEnumerator()
        => new NotImplementedIterator();
}
class NotImplementedIterator
{
    public bool MoveNext() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public ref int Current => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new Foo();
        foreach(ref int x in obj)
        {
            x = 42; // this assigns **via the ref**
        }
    }
}
```

So: what you're talking about *is possible right now*. Because it is assigning *via a reference*, this can push changes directly into the underlying source.

It just ... isn't very common because *that isn't what people expect when iterating over data*.

1. they only *expect* to be able to read
2. iterators are common on **immutable** data
3. the existing interfaces only support the read concept
4. it requires functionality like `ref`-return which is not well understood by most developers *and* which cannot be used from all .NET languages
5. ref return *is only sensible in some small set of scenarios*

Comment: I think it is strange that people don't want to write to iterable data containers. Or rather, I think it is strange that I have such a hard time with it while all others seem get along with <other solution> just fine. What is <other solution> for most folks?